# Characterization of Hausdorff without using LEM

Tags: general-topology, alternative-proof

This question is about the 'unique extension property' as defined [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2315068?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents), which is: A topological space $Y$ has the unique extension property if, for any topological space $X$, any two continuos functions from $X$ into $Y$ which agree on a dense subset of $X$ are equal. This property is equivalent to the set $Y$ being Hausdorff as has been proved in the mentioned article as well as in a previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9825/does-this-property-characterize-a-space-as-hausdorff).

My question is, can it be proved that the unique extension property implies Hausdorffness *without* using LEM, that is, without using the contrapositive? (Preferably without using the axiom of choice)

Comment: The LEM and AC are true and uncontroversial in general. Just use them whenever you like! Don't cramp your style...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof that UEP implies Hausdorff can also be given thusly: let $x \neq y$ in $X$.

Then consider $X \times X$ in the product topology and let $f_1$,$f_2$ be the two continuous projections and let $D:=\{(x,x) \mid x \in X\}$. Then $D$ is by definition dense in $Y=\overline{D}$ (closure taken in $X \times X$) and $f_1 \restriction_D = f_2\restriction_D$ and so $f_1 = f_2$ on $Y$ which means that $\overline{D} = D$ as $f_1 \neq f_2$ outside $D$, in particular $x=f_1(x,y)=f_2(x,y)=y$.

So $(x,y) \notin \overline{D}$ which means that there is a (basic) open neighbourhood $U \times V$ of $(x,y)$ that misses $D$, and this implies $U \cap V = \emptyset$.

But to avoid the LEM you'd have to set up topology in quite a different way. See intuitionistic topology and such theories. Some use of proofs by contradiction, or use of the contrapositive is unavoidable, and shouldn't be avoided unless one is a very strict constructivist/intuitionist/finitist etc., in which case you have to throw away most of standard maths anyway. I think the above argument could be acceptable to the OP, I hope. It's inspired on the fact that $X$ is Hausdorff iff the diagonal is closed in $X^2$ (which proof also uses some contrapositive), and which has the advantage of working in any space, $T_1$ or not, and not using nets (as some proofs do).

Comment: Yep I a not a intuitionist or anything like that but I do agree with them that constructive proofs are more elegant. While your proof may not be intuitionistic strictly speaking I do think it is 'nicer' than the ones I linked. Thanks!

Comment: @Shiranai It's a bit more direct maybe. But it's also nice to think about the contrapositive of Hausdorffness to get a feel for it.

Comment: Agree, I normally try to prove both the normal one and contrapositive :)