# Characterization of Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms

When we study Hausdorff space, we can have the following two results:

**Cor. 173**

> If $f,g: X \to Y$ are continuous and $Y$ is $T_2$, then $\{x \in X\mid f(x) = g(x)\}$ is closed in $X$.

**Cor. 174**

> If $f,g:X \to Y$ are continuous and $Y$ is $T_2$ and $\{x \in X\mid f(x)=g(x)\}$ is a dense subset of $X$, then $f=g$.

In fact, these two statements can be used to **characterize** Hausdorff.

**For 173, we have characterization 1:**

if $Y$ is not Hausdorff,  there always exists a topological space $X$ and two continuous functions $f$ and $g$, such that the set $\{x | f(x) = g(x)\}$ is not closed.

Thus, “a space Y is Hausdorff if and only if for every topological space X and for any continuous maps from X to Y, the set $\{x | f(x) = g(x)\}$ is closed.” is a characterization of Hausdorff Space.

**174 is similar, we have characterization 2:**

$Y$ is Hausdorff, if and only if whenever we have $f$ and $g$ continuous from any space $X$, and $\{x | f(x) = g(x)\}$ is a dense subset of $X$, then $f=g$”

My question is: How to prove these, i.e., How to find examples to prove the other direction of **characterization 1,2**?

Characterization 2 already has an answer here:
[Does this property characterize a space as Hausdorff?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/9825/549321)

Comment: Please write all mathematical results in the text itself instead of posting a picture.  This makes it more searchable and is easier to read.  (With more than three years on this site, you are not a "beginner" anymore :-)

Comment: @PatrickR I followed up on your request. Sorry to encourage laziness this way but it benefits the site..

Comment: @HennoBrandsma You are too nice!  I was expecting the asker would do it.

Comment: @Beginner We have been talking about it on Meta: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34216 Hope you can do that in the future, especially since the mathematical contents of your questions is good.  That will benefit everyone.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121

Comment: @PatrickR, Thank you for your patience, I would not put the central part of the problem just in a picture in the future, and I understand that I can only use images to demonstrate some supportive/auxiliary content, in order to make my question searchable, accessible... Thank you for all of your effort to make this community better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any directed set $I$ (such as we use in [nets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics))) we define $X(I):=I \cup \{\infty\}$ where $I$ consists of isolated points and a basic neighbourhood of $\infty$ is of the form $\{\infty\} \cup \{i \in I: \mid i \ge i_0\}$ where $i_0 \in I$ is arbitrary. It's easily shown that this defines a topological space. In it$ I$ is dense and non-closed.

Then if $Y$ is *not* Hausdorff we have a net $(x_i)_{i \in I}$ in $Y$ that converges to two distinct points $p\neq q \in Y$.

Then defining $f,g: X(I) \to Y$ by $f(i)=x_i = g(i)$ and $f(\infty)=p, g(\infty)=q$ we easily check that both are continuous maps (due to the net converging to both points), and $I=\{x\mid f(x)=g(x)\}$ is both not a closed set and also dense despite $f \neq g$. So both claims are shown at the same time.

Comment: You could probably do this with a filter space as well, if that rocks your boat. But he, I like nets and this is a natural idea.

Comment: I think you should have written $f(\infty) = p$ and $g(\infty) = q$.