# If $f$ and $g$  are continuous and  for every $q\in \mathbb{Q}$ we have $f(q)=g(q)$, then $f(x)=g(x)$ for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can there be two distinct, continuous functions that are equal at all rationals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/505/can-there-be-two-distinct-continuous-functions-that-are-equal-at-all-rationals)

Hello guys,

Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous functions, $f,g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, such that for every $q\in \mathbb{Q}$ we have $f(q)=g(q)$.

I need to prove that $f(x)=g(x)$ for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

I think I should prove that with sequences. We can choose a $x\in \mathbb{R}$, and we know
that there is a sequence of rational numbers whose limit is $x$. Let's call it $X_{n}$, so $\lim f(X_{n})=\lim g(X_{n})$, when $n \to \infty $, and we get what we want.

Is it correct? What do you think?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Yes. Your method is right. You may want to prove continuity and sequentially continuity are the same.

Comment: Yes, that is essentially correct. You might want to be more explicit about how the sequence is constructed, and why you can take limits like that.

Comment: @Sivaram: They are the same under this context, not in the full mathematical context.

Comment: @Asaf: Yes they are the same in this context. But in case he has not proved the equivalence of the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition and sequential definition.

Comment: @Sivaram: Perhaps he did before? I do agree that it is wise to remark that.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9532/link-between-a-dense-subset-and-a-continuous-mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Consider h=f-g, which is identically zero  for all $q\in \mathbb{Q}$. Assume
 h(x)= a , for some irrational x, and a is non-zero. Then any e-ball around x will necessarily contain rationals. Choose an e-value that will prevent continuity for any
choice of delta, re a delta-epsilon proof.

Comment: I think you want your e-ball around x, not around a.

Comment: w($ild)^3$life: you are right, I just edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are continuous real valued functions.  Then $[f = g] = \{x| f(x) = g(x)\}$ is just the set of points $x$ for which $f(x) - g(x) = 0$.  By continuity, this is a closed set because it is the inverse image of a single point under a continuous function.  So if $f$ and $g$ are real continuous functions and $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x\in E$ then $f(x) = g(x)% on the closure of $E$.

Therefore if $f$ and $g$ agree on a dense subset of their domain, they agree on the entire domain; to wit, f = g.  This entire argument works very nicely if $f$ and $g$ are defined on an arbitrary metric space.