# why separable normal space has only continuum many different open subsets?

Tags: general-topology

I cannot prove the fact in the title. Please help!
I am reading the handbook of set theoretic topology.
And I found this fact in a proof in the book.

Thank you.

Comment: For the determination of the used nomenclature: A normal space is one that is $T_4$ and $T_1$ in that handbook?

Comment: To be more precise, I am reading the chapter 18 of the book. As mentioned in the introduction, the author follows the definition in Engelking's book. The author also assumes that all spaces are completely regular.

Comment: Is it true that $|C(X)|\ge |\tau|$  for a normal space  $(X,\tau)$, where $C(X)$ is the set of real-valued continuous functions on $X$? ($|C(X)|\le c$ for separable $X$.)

Comment: Hi David, can please tell me why |C(X)|$ \leq$ c for separable X

Comment: See the first answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9532/link-between-a-dense-subset-and-a-continuous-mapping).

Comment: @Jessy: Exactly where in Teodor’s chapter did you find this assertion?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: please read the answer provide by hot_queen below.

Answer (score 2):

This is false: $X = 2^{2^{\omega}}$ under the usual product topology is a counterexample. It is obviously normal being compact Hausdorff. Checking that $X$ is separable is a fun exercise. Finally, $X$ has more than continuum many points and hence more than continuum many open sets. The correct upper bound is $2^{2^{\omega}}$ and you can prove this by showing that $\{\{x \in X: f(x) \neq 0\} \mid f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous$\}$ is a basis of size at most continuum. The above example shows that this bound is optimal.

Addendum: I looked at chapter 18 and noticed that the proof of Jones' lemma on page 784 contains the pharse "Since $X$ is separable, it has only continuum many different open sets ..." which is incorrect. The correct argument goes as follows: Given $F$ discrete closed in $X$, for each $K \subseteq F$, get an open set $U_K$ such that $K \subseteq U_K, \overline{U_K} \cap (F \setminus K) = \phi$. Let $D$ be countable dense in $X$. Suppose $K, K'$ are distinct subsets of $F$ and say $x \in K \setminus K'$. Let $x \in V \subseteq U_{K}$ where $V$ is open and disjoint with $U_{K'}$. Then $D \cap V \subseteq U_K \backslash U_{K'}$. Hence the map $K \mapsto U_K \cap D$ is injective. So $2^{|F|} \leq 2^{|D|} = 2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: Right, $X=\beta \mathbb{N}$ can serve as another counterexample as it is separable by the very definition.

Comment: @ hot_queen: thank you for your answer. I am still new in this field so, could you please tell me what is the countable dense set in $X= 2^{2^{\omega}}$?

Comment: @ Tomek kania: same question as above, please provide me the countable dense set in your given space

Comment: For each $n < \omega$ and $A \subseteq 2^n$, define $f_A \in 2^{2^{\omega}}$ by $f_{A}(x) = 1$ iff $x$ is a branch through a node in $A$. Try to show that $\{f_A : n < \omega, A \subseteq 2^n\}$ is dense in $2^{2^{\omega}}$.

Comment: @ hot_queen: I got it