# Organizing types of functions by their calculus-related properties, in diagram form?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, reference-request, complex-analysis, functions

Does anyone know of a diagram that displays and organizes categories of functions according to their calculus-related properties (e.g. continuous, $C^\infty$, degrees of differentiability and integrability; not so much things like even/odd, one-to-one)?  Something along the lines of what this diagram does for complex numbers.

[image: Complex Number Venn Diagram]

[The original of this (and more) can be found [here](http://thinkzone.wlonk.com/Numbers/NumberSets.pdf).]

I would be grateful if you could direct me to any good resources that categorize types of functions in a systematic and succinct manner.  Illuminating examples of the different types of functions (e.g. Weierstrass's continuous-everywhere-but-differentiable-nowhere function) and schematic clarity would be pluses.

Let me know if you need more information.  Thanks!

**Edit**: I've look around more on this site at related questions (notably [Are the smooth functions dense in either $\mathcal L_2$ or $\mathcal L_1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8504/are-the-smooth-functions-dense-in-either-l2-or-l1) and [what is the cardinality of set of all smooth functions in $L^1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9395/what-is-the-cardinality-of-set-of-all-smooth-functions-in-l1)) and found them intriguing and somewhat helpful. I could really use help putting all of these and many other pieces together, though.  Any takers?

Comment: Is there really a nice hierarchy? Sure you could split functions up into analytic ones, meromorphic ones, those functions with branch cuts... and then genuine monsters, but what's the point of a hierarchy?

Comment: I don't know if there's a hierarchy or interesting interactions of categories. I'm asking because I don't know this terrain very well and am hoping for a better and more unified understanding of the possibilities, intricacies, and surprises that exist. One thing I've thought of is how there's continuous>C^1>...>C^inf. I'm not sure what all else is going on.

Comment: You might find this book somewhat helpful: http://books.google.com/books?id=cDAMh5n4lkkC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the book *A Second Course on Real Functions* by van Rooij & Schikhof:

[image]

[image]

The publisher allows you to read excerpts online: [the introduction](http://assets.cambridge.org/97805212/83618/excerpt/9780521283618_excerpt.pdf), where this figure is taken from, and [the table of contents](http://assets.cambridge.org/97805212/83618/frontmatter/9780521283618_frontmatter.pdf), including a four-page list of examples & counterexamples.

Comment: This is really nice, Marius. These are interesting categories, and I like how the introduction gives examples of functions that lie in the different regions. Thanks for your answer! Also: are there any categories that you could think to add?

Comment: You're welcome! And here is, incidentally, [a similar diagram](http://www.ams.org/notices/200109/fea-saloff.pdf) (Fig 3) on a completely different topic.

Answer (score 1):

In your diagram: delete the Imaginary axis, change Integer to "Polynomial with a finite number of terms", change Rational to Rational function, change Algebraic to Algebraic function. I'm not sure what Real corresponds to. On another axis you could have the C^1>C^2 ... as you mentioned. On another axis you could have the field of the polynomial, i.e. "polynomial over integers", "polynomial over real", "polynomial over complex", "polynomial over vector space", etc.